# videojs with brightcove giving error using require.ensure in React component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, requirejs, video.js, brightcove

I'm trying to use require.ensure in my react component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    require.ensure([], () => {
        require('public/jscripts/brightcove/index.js');
    });
}
```

but keep getting an error: `Cannot set property 'default' of undefined`

It happens at this point in the brightcove videojs script:

```
// At this point, `window.videojs` will be the earliest-defined copy of this
// version of videojs.
var videojs = window.videojs;

// https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2698
videojs['default'] = videojs;
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

The full script is here btw, I saved it as a local file hence the path `public/jscripts/brightcove/index.js`: https://players.brightcove.net/1752604059001/B1xXFuBodW_default/index.js

Comment: Isnt this just about missing of videojs dependency? Try `require.ensure(['video.js'], () => { require('public/jscripts/brightcove/index.js'); });`

Comment: Are you including `video.js` before? Also, in video.js documentation, it is stated the following: `Next, using Video.js is as simple as creating a <video> element, but with an additional data-setup attribute. At a minimum, this attribute must have a value of '{}', but it can include any Video.js options - just make sure it contains valid JSON!`